# Django prefetch_related and performance optimisation with multiple QuerySets within loops

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-2.2

Effectively I have multiple Queries within loops that I am just not happy with. I am seeking some expertise with `prefetch_related` and other Django Query construction optimisations.

I start with:

```
users = User.objects.filter(organisation=organisation).filter(is_active=True)
```

Then, I start my loop over all days starting from a certain date "`start_date`":

```
for date in (start_date + datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range((datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC) - start_date).days + 1)):
```

I then within this loop over a filtered subset of the above `users`

```
for date in (start_date + datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range((datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC) - start_date).days + 1)):
  for user in users.filter(created_date__lte=date).iterator():
```

Firstly, is there any way to optimise this?

What may make some of the hardcore Django-ers lose their tether, I do all of the above inside another loop!

```
for survey in Survey.objects.all().iterator():
   for date in (start_date + datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range((datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC) - start_date).days + 1)):
      for user in users.filter(created_date__lte=date).iterator():
```

Inside the last loop, I perform one final Query filter:

```
survey_result = SurveyResult.objects.filter(survey=survey, user=user, created_date__lte=date).order_by('-updated_date')[0]
```

I do this because I feel I need to have the user, survey and date variables ready to filter...

I have started thinking about prefetch_related and the Prefetch object. I've consulted the documentation but I can't seem to apply this to my situation.

Effectively, the query is taking far too long. For an average of 1000 users, 4 surveys and approximately 30 days, this query is taking 1 minute to complete.

Ideally, I would like to shave off 50% of this. Any better, and I will be extremely happy. I'd also like the load on the DB server to be reduced as this query could be running multiple times across different organisations.

I'd also like to improve how to organise such horrific queries within loops within loops!

Full "condensed" minimum viable snippet:

```
users = User.objects.filter(organisation=organisation).filter(is_active=True)

datasets = []

for survey in Survey.objects.all():
    data = []
    for date in (start_date + datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range((datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC) - start_date).days + 1)):
        total_score = 0
        participants = 0

        for user in users.filter(created_date__lte=date):
             participants += 1
             survey_result = SurveyResult.objects.filter(survey=survey, user=user, created_date__lte=date).order_by('-updated_date')[0]
             total_score += survey_result.score
      
        # An average is calculated from the total_score and participants and append to the data array.:
        # Divide catches divide by zero errors.
        # Round will round to two decimal places for front end readability.
        data.append(
            round(
                divide(total_score, participants), 2
            )
        )

    datasets.append(data)
```

### Addendum

So, further to @dirkgroten's answer I am currently running with:

```
for survey in Survey.objects.all():

                results = SurveyResult.objects.filter(
                    user__in=users, survey=survey, created_date__range=date_range
                ).values(
                    'survey',
                    'created_date',
                ).annotate(
                    total_score=Sum('normalized_score'),
                    participants=Count('user'),
                    average_score=Avg('normalized_score'),
                ).order_by(
                    'created_date'
                )

                for result in results:
                    print(result)
```

As I think I need a breakdown by survey for each QuerySet.

Are there any other optimisations available to me?

Comment: Please do *not* use `.iterator()` unless you really need it. Without it, you load the entire set in a bulk.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I hear that the case I’ve used it for is the exact time to use it tho...

Comment: As in, I’ve already called a Query which is cached because I then need a subset iterator over that subset so I don’t think I need it cached. Does that make sense?

Comment: I miss one thing in your question: what's the end result you're trying to get? i.e. what do you do with `survey_result` (you have 1000 * 4 * 30 of them)? That might help to figure out whether this can be done in one query.

Comment: @dirkgroten I perform various sums and aggregations to the result score, access as attribute survey_result.score for all users for a specific day broken down by the survey (for an analytics dashboard). I have an aggregates table which did perform a lot of the heavy lifting - but this particular view has some more customisable filtering parameters which are loosely defined.

Comment: I think you need to show that, because I have the feeling you can do this (including the aggregations) inside one query. Please add the entire code, or at least the input parameters (I can see `organisation` and `start_date`) and the desired output.

Comment: @dirkgroten See amended code, I believe it should all be there to perform what I may possibly need.

Comment: Not exactly, what's the end result? How are you aggregating each `total_score` and `participants` into something you can use after the for loops are done? A big nested dictionary? A list of tuples?

Comment: @dirkgroten I have a serialiser that handles the output. Ideally, I would like these two variables to be just that - variables. Evaluated for each survey in Survey.objects.all(). A grand serialized dataset is then constructed on the fly, which would be some sort of dictionary.

Comment: But right now, your code snippet creates 4 * 30 (no. surveys * no. dates) values for `participants` and `total_score` without saving them anywhere. When your loops are done, you've lost all these values. I'm just asking how you store them, so that you can access these values per survey and per date.

Comment: @dirkgroten Ah, ok so the final values are the average daily score, taken from dividing the `total_score` (aggregated sum of individual user's score) divided by the number of `participants` for each day. These values are then smushed into an array, of values like: `[75.4, 56.7,45.8,49.2,89.1]` which are easily consumed by a chart.js frontend. The array is constructed iteratively as: `dataset['dataset']['data'].append(round(divide(total_score, participants), 2))` as shown in the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually combine queries and perform the calculations directly inside your query:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Count, Avg
from django.utils import timezone
users = User.objects.filter(organisation=organisation).filter(is_active=True)
date_range = [start_date, timezone.now().date]  # or adapt end time to different time zone
results = SurveyResult.objects.filter(user__in=users, created_date__range=date_range)\
              .values('survey', 'created_date')\
              .annotate(total_score=Sum('score'), participants=Count('pk'))
              .order_by('survey', 'created_date')
```

This will group the results by `survey` and `created_date` and add the `total_score` and `participants` to each result, something like:

```
[{'survey': 1, 'created_date': '2019-08-05', 'total_score': 54, 'participants': 20}, 
 {'survey': 1, ... } ... ]
```

I'm assuming there's only one `SurveyResult` per user so the number of `SurveyResult` in each group is the number of participants.

Note that `Avg` also gives you the average score at once, that is assuming only one possible score per user:

```
.annotate(average_score=Avg('score'))  # instead of total and participants
```

This should shave off 99.9% of your query time :-)

If you want the dataset as a list of lists, you just do something like this:

```
dataset = []
data = []
current_survey = None
current_date = start_date
for result in results
    if not result['survey'] == current_survey:
        # results ordered by survey, so if it changes, reset data
        if data: dataset.append(data)            
        data = []
        current_survey = result['survey']
    if not result['created_date'] == current_date:
        # results ordered by date so missing date won't be there later 
        # assume a daterange function to create a list of dates
        for date in daterange(current_date, result['created_date']):
            data.append(0)  # padding data
     current_date = result['created_date']
     data.append(result['average_score'])
```

The result will be a list of lists:

```
dataset = [[0, 0, 10.4, 3.9, 0], [20.2, 3.5, ...], ...]
```

Not super efficient python, but with a few 1000 results, this will be super fast anyway, way faster than performing more db queries.

**EDIT**: Since created_date is `DateTimeField`, you first need to get the corresponding date:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate
results = SurveyResult.objects.filter(user__in=users, created_date__range=date_range)
               .annotate(date=TruncDate('created_date'))
               .values('survey', 'date')
               .annotate(average_score=Avg('score'))
               .order_by('survey', 'date')
```

Comment: Hi Dirk, can I just work on this and get back to you if I have any questions/queries or if I am able to accept this as an answer. This could be promising.

Comment: Of course. I haven't tried it in my console, there might be a typo somewhere. Here's the [link to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation).

Comment: Hmmmm, ok - so the front end needs each of the survey types as a separated dataset. As well as any empty days, i.e., where there is no data since the start date to be 0. So every day needs to be accounted for from the `start_date`. I'm also seeing the reduced value for `participants` as `1` for every day.

Comment: So, I assume now, I need to work with this query set an aggregate further?

Comment: You can process the list in python to group by survey and add the missing dates values (that's fast and doesn't involve any db query anymore). As to the wrong number of participants, is 'user' a fk in `SurveyResult` or the other way round?

Comment: I think I misunderstood my own dataset - apologies. I think what I have now, annotated, could be enough. Would you be happy if I were to say I break-up/filter the SurveyResult query into four sub queries, one for each survey. I do this via a loop. Do you think this could be optimised any further? (See the addition to my question, as my settled snippet, what do you think?)

Comment: I would loop over the results to break it up instead of performing 4 queries (this effectively makes the total query time 4x slower). Also I fixed your participants count in my answer, you should not Count('user') but Count('pk').

Comment: Ok, so remove `results` from the loop, and loop over `Survey.objects.all()` separately?

Comment: Would it be ok to show me a rough example of how to filter `results` using a `for survey in Survey.objects.all()` loop, could I just do `results.filter(survey=survey.id)` ?

Comment: `results` is a QuerySet, so yes, you could add a `filter` after it, but this will create a new QuerySet (and so you'll end up having 4 different queries to the db). It depends how fast the query is now. If you can live with the 4 different queries because everything is now super fast (which I expect), it's more readable to indeed loop through the surveys. If not, it's more efficient but less readable to loop through the `results` and populate your `dataset` item by item.

Comment: I added an order, which makes it easier to populate `dataset` when looping through the results (you can directly check for missing dates).

Comment: Awesome, I added an `order_by` for `created_date`. I'm going to run with surveys = Survey.objects.all().values('id'), and then loop over `results` using `surveys`. With no more queries.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to filter, it just produces four of the same set for each of the loop iterations...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197567/discussion-between-wind-up-lord-vexxos-and-dirkgroten).